# How can I improve my Capoeira low game other than "just doing it"?

Tags: drills, capoeira

I used to do *Capoeira regional* while I lived in Philadelphia. I now live in Pittsburgh where the primary game is *Capoeira Angola*. One of the issues I'm running into is that my low game is not great. Most of our drills are upright, and that seems to be what the student leading the class (we lack a proper *mestre*) is comfortable teaching. Are there any drills for improving one's low game, sequences linking one movement to another while staying low?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like any activity where you want to make those kinds of improvements; Visualisation is your friend. See yourself in your mind making those sequence links and keeping low. Do this over and over to get comfortable in your mind that you will be able to do the moves you want.

The other thing is flexibility and strength. Both can be worked on separately, holding the position you need to off the ground. Transitioning through the moves very slowly so that you get comfortable and strong at every inch of this movement.

Comment: Can you suggest sequences?

Comment: I would concentrate on being able to hold your own weight off the ground , as low as possible to the ground. This would really involve working though your comfort levels, and slowly accumulating confidence and strength to do any techniques.

Answer (score 2):

Bryan Garrett proposed doing Benguela games. This might actually something you want to do. As Benguela was designed to help students of Capoeira Contemporânea to develop a low game that then can lead to the game played with toce de angola. ( https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benguela_(capoeira) ).
Sequences always change and depend mostly on your teacher (and group). But remove all Jinga, only do Cadeira, Negativa, Role, different Aus (com e sin Cabeça no chão) and you got a solid basis of defensive moves you can combine to your own movements. Add to them kicks that always start from and end on the floor and you get more variety. Remember that different groups have different movements to the different toques.
Maybe you should look up some workshops on weekends so that you can learn this part from another teacher.

Comment: :) Eyeh, there aren't many groups here in Pittsburgh currently (there used to be more, but people moved). But thank you for the advice.

Comment: A big part of capoeira is travelling around and meet other people. So maybe you want to look up groups in other cities and see when they have workshops. If you ask them they might be open to take in people from other groups as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you're training Angola,.. but have you considered trying [CDO Miudinho sequences](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M92w3a28hUw)?  From my experience, its a great way to rep ground movements.

Comment: Welcome to the site. This is a seed of a good answer but could you describe the CDO Miudinho sequences and tell us why, in your experience, this answers the question.

Comment: {nods} CDO would be Cordao De Ouro. I think this might be the sequences he's talking about: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M92w3a28hUw

Comment: Yes, Sean those are some of the sequences; and yes CDO = a capoeira group called Cordão de Ouro. Sardathrion -thnx for the welcome. These sequences involve defending from attacks by [falling to the ground] into movements like queda-de-rin, negative angola, etc.. and flowing into other ground movements like ponte, au cordão de ouro, volta per cima, etc. Sean asked for a suggestion of DRILLS/SEQUENCES... I'm not sure why I'd have to include an explanation of WHY in my answer when WHY was not in the question

Comment: btw Sean you may wanna research benguela games also. It's not my style, but from what I've seen they use a ton of ground movements as well