# Is there any textual description available for the Cordao de Ouro Miudinho Sequences?

Tags: forms, capoeira

In response to my question, [How can I improve my Capoeira low game other than "just doing it"?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/6908/how-can-i-improve-my-capoeira-low-game-other-than-just-doing-it), the suggestion was made to try the *Miudinho* sequences as used by the *Cordao de Ouro* group. I've found a good video depiction of the sequences [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M92w3a28hUw), but I'm a textual learner in a lot of ways. Is there a book or other source of information indicating the moves involved in these sequences? The closest I've found is an [iTunes app](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWt5Z9zsk_g) (which no longer seems to be available) which is of little use to me because I don't own an Apple tablet.

Comment: Asked a friend of mine who is a professor in a different school system, and he wasn't aware of any other than the video.

Comment: @JohnP: Thank you for following up. I guess I'll just have to make my own transcript. :)

Comment: He said his school is not that "nice", and noted the sequences are intended to be a fun game that is kind of tricky, but not aggressive.

Comment: @JohnP: Can he comment whether the sequences are a fixed set of movements, or if it's more of a general concept? It's been unclear to me when trying to read up on it. It certainly looks like a rehearsed sequence, but that can often apply to playing at a high level.

Comment: Fixed sequences done with partners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I [asked this question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/capoeira/comments/92ckp9/miudinho_cordao_de_ouro_sequencia/) and got an answer that this is actually several *Cordão de Ouro* sequences. There is no written version. The app just broke it down into the individual sequences.

It looks like [it's now available for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appsolutegroup.cdo), but as per the Reddit thread, there's no textual description and, honestly, the low framerate for the sections is mildly nauseating, at least for me.

My transcript:

| Capoeiristra A | Capoeiristra B |
| --- | --- |
| Begin in cocorinha | *Same* |
| Negativa, right | Negativa, left |
| Rolê right | Rolê left |
| Troca, rolê left | Rolê left |
| Aú fechado left | *Same* |
| Land negativa left | *Same* |
| Aú fechado left, land legs straight, feet together | *Same* |
| Aú fechado right, land legs straight, feet together | *Same* |
| Aú fechado left, land legs straight, feet together | *Same* |
| Rolê right to queda de quatro | *Same* |
| Aú de cabeça right | *Same* |
| Aú de cabeça left | *Same* |
| Meia lua de compasso right, stop at contact | *Same* |
| Brief bananeira with legs at waist height | *Same* |
| Land on right foot, extend left foot to circle opponent with back to them | *Same* |
| Stand and turn to partner | *Same* |
| Resistencia, right hand down | Bênção right |
| Turn to tesoura de angola, begin standing up | Queda de tres under rising partner |
| Turn left, raising right leg over partner | Turn to prone position, and slide under partner |
| Land with right leg back, shift right leg forward while blocking kick with both hands | Escorpiao left |
| Turn to the right and place hands on the ground, tesoura de Angola | Stand, aú right |
| Meia lua de compasso left | Negativa da Regional left |
| Meia lua de compasso right | Rolê left |
| Resistencia to rolê right | Meia lua de compasso left |
| Tesoura de Angola | Jump to QDR right |
| Stand, jump to QDR right | Tesoura de Angola |
| Tesoura de Angola | Stand, roll over back, land standing |
| Shoot left leg to back, rolê right to standing | Ginga to face partner |